# Regex that would give certain words python

Tags: python, regex, split

I am looking for a regex that gives words starting with letters, numbers or underscore ('_'). It can only include dot ('.') between the words and not at the end and should remove all other special characters.
e.g

```
WARC-_Target-URI: http://www.allchocolate.com/health/basics/
```

should give

WARC, _Target, URI, http, www.allchocolate.com, health, basics

Any sort of help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you are:

```
from re import findall

print findall(r'\w[\w.]*\w', 'WARC-_Target-URI: http://www.allchocolate.com/health/basics/')
```

> ['WARC', '_Target', 'URI', 'http', 'www.allchocolate.com', 'health', 'basics']

Unlike the other solutions, this will work in any situation (not just the example that you posted).

Comment: it is almost correct. Just 1 problem with this solution. It is also giving words with dot ('.') at the end. e.g for 'good for you.' should give 'good', 'for', 'you' but it is giving 'good', 'for', 'you.'.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
test = "WARC-_Target-URI: http://www.allchocolate.com/health/basics/"
print re.findall(r"[\w'.]+", test)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
s = 'WARC-_Target-URI: http://www.allchocolate.com/health/basics/'

parts = [x for x in re.split(r'[/:-]',s) if x]

print(parts)

['WARC', '_Target', 'URI', ' http', 'www.allchocolate.com', 'health', 'basics']
```